# Get list of given arguments in octave

Tags: matlab, octave

So, I want to make some calculations using the arguments I passed in the function.

My function looks like this `function f=myFunc(arg1,arg2,arg3)` and I can give 2 or more arguments in total.
I call it from the command windows as `myFunc(2.0,3.4,1.6)`.

I want to calculate the product of those numbers which is easy if the number of arguments was constant and not dynamic.

**Is there a way to get those arguments into a list to use it later as I please?**

Something like that:

`myList=function_args()`

`>>>[2.0,3.4,1.6]`

so I can pass the list to the prod function `prod(myList)`

Comment: You can if you declare the function as `f=myFunc(varargin)`; see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html)

Comment: @LuisMendo that can be done with N arguments? Because in some tutorials I watched, everyone uses case

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. `varargin` is the way for the function to receive an arbitrary number of arguments, from 0 to arbitrarily large.